# Select named array from a hash of array of arrays

Tags: ruby

I have a hash of an array of arrays. The array is indexed by the hash (that is the way I am reading this):

```
[
 {"name":"G18","data": [["X301",141],["x7901",57],["x2100",142],["x90",58]]},
 {"name":"G19","data": [["M16",141],["M203",57],["M29S",142]]},
 {"name":"G20","data": [["X301",141],["x7901",57],["x2100",142],["x90",58]]}
]
```

I want to select the hashes that contain the array `G18`, and return only the data.

I tried searching for answer, but I haven't found anything like this yet.

Comment: Please edit to state whether the number of hashes `h` for which `h.key("name") #=> true` and `h["name"] === "Gi8" #=> true` can be zero or more than one.

Comment: Note `"G18"` is not an array and you presumably mean that you want to return the *value* of `:data`. If you assign a variable to your array (`arr = [{...`) you could say that you "wish to return `h[:data]` for the element of  `h` of `arr` for which `h[:name] == "G18"`is `true`. That assumes there is exactly one such hash `h` having that property. If zero or more than one could have that property, the statement would have to be adjusted according.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you if you have only one item with name "G18":

```
a.find {|e| e[:name] == "G18" }[:data]
```

See: [*Enumerable#find*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) in the official docs.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem, greatly appreciated.

Comment: `a.find {|e| e[:name] == "G17" }[:data]` raises an exception because  `a.find {|e| e[:name] == "G17" } #=> nil` and there is no method `NilClass#[]`. You could use Ruby's [Safe Navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) to deal with this case: `a.find {|e| e[:name] == "G17" }&.[](:data) #=> nil`. Note that you cannot write `a.find {|e| e[:name] == "G17" }&.[:data]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland , blame me not -)) just tell those mad [pythonistas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815210/transform-float-to-int-so-that-every-information-is-preserved-or-how-to-get-the) that they need basic arithmetics, not decimal handling libraries, string representations, logarithms etc -))

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
ary = [
  {"name":"G18","data": [["X301",141],["x7901",57],["x2100",142],["x90",58]]},
  {"name":"G19","data": [["M16",141],["M203",57],["M29S",142]]},
  {"name":"G20","data": [["X301",141],["x7901",57],["x2100",142],["x90",58]]}
]
```

Try:

```
ary.select{|hsh| hsh[:name] == 'G18'}.first[:data]
 => [["X301", 141], ["x7901", 57], ["x2100", 142], ["x90", 58]]
```

In fact, marmeladze's answer is the correct one:

```
ary.find{|hsh| hsh[:name] == 'G18'}[:data]
```

Using `select` was a misfire.

Answer (score 2):

```
collection = [
  {"name":"G18","data": [["X301",141],["x7901",57],["x2100",142],["x90",58]]},
  {"name":"G19","data": [["M16",141],["M203",57],["M29S",142]]},
  {"name":"G20","data": [["X301",141],["x7901",57],["x2100",142],["x90",58]]}
]

def data_for_name(name, collection)
  collection.find { |item| item[:name] == name }[:data]
end

p data_for_name("G18", collection)
```

Comment: How does this differ from @marmeladze's earlier answer?

Comment: It's always a good idea in Ruby to extract logic such as this into methods.

In this case, doing so allows this code to work with any collection of hashes that have `name` and `data` keys. Also lets us defer until runtime the decision as to what item we're looking for.

Comment: I think what you said is obvious and could be applied equally to any SO answer that has not been wrapped in the obvious method.

Comment: @CarySwoveland -- As someone who teachers beginners how to code, this is certainly not obvious.