# Transform float to int so that every information is preserved OR how to get the lenght of a long float

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, type-conversion, precision

In Python, I receive two floats e.g.

```
a = 0.123456
b = 0.012340
```

and a precision

```
p = 0.000001
```

that tells me there will be no digits beyond the 6th decimal of the floats.
I want to transform the floats to two integers, so that every information they carry is represented in the integers.

```
int_a = 137632
int_b = 12340
```

The solution in this case is obviously to multiply them by 1000000, but I can't figure out a smart way to get there.
I tried the workaround to get the number of digits in p by:

```
len(str(p))-1 //-1 because of the dot.
```

But:

```
>>> str(p)
>>> 1e-06
```

Well I could replace the "-" by a "+" in the string and transform it back to a float, but this seems for me to be a pretty ugly approach and I thought there must be a much cleaner, mathematical way to do that.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I think you'll find the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) library to be useful.

Comment: You probably want something like `-math.log10(p)`, but then, since you are using floating point numbers, this approach will be fraught with pitfalls

Answer (score 2):

Why you just do not multiply `a` and `b` with `1/p` ?

```
int(a * 1/p) 
int(b * 1/p)
```

You exactly do not need python (or its string methods) other than converting resulting floats to integer, just arithmetics -))

Comment: haha thousand thanks! I knew there must be an incredibly easy answer. I feel a little bit stupid now^^ maybe I should call it a day.

Comment: the devil is in the  detail :p

Comment: The negative powers of ten are not representable in binary floating point, so the `p` in the problem statement will contain a rounding error, and so will the divison, This may cause incorrect results in the method proposed in this answer.

Comment: i only used python to convert floats to integer - and my answer is just a standpoint how to solve. other than this, i think, representation of p in python and p itself are different things,   `print(p)` or `p` outputs 1e-06, on shell,  but  1/p is still 10^6 and when we multiply with another number, it still acts as we expect.

Comment: Given `a = .000493` and `p = .000001`, `int(a * 1/p)` produces an answer of 492, when 493 may be expected. (This is due to `a` not being what it may appear.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right! I figured out I can avoid it by using math.ceil(a*math.ceil(1/p)). But I don't really understand the underlying problem here about the binary representation of floating points. Is my math.ceil approach valid or will it just lead to other complications? Cheers

Comment: `math.ceil(a*math.ceil(1/p))` returns the desired answer for `a = .000493` but not for `a = .000492`. As with many questions like this, the OP is trying to work with floating-point values as decimal numerals, but the information is already lost before they start. In this case, `round(a/p)` may suffice. That is assuming OP really meant it when they said “there will be no digits beyond the [place described by `p`].”